# How should I caulk between bathtub and drywall?

Tags: bathtub, caulking

My tub sits in an alcove that is 6 inches wider than the width of the tub at the head, and sits against a full wall at the foot. I tiled the alcove but stopped at the front edge of the tub so that painted drywall is exposed and meets at the tub at it's full height in the front.

I've used non-paintable silicone caulking already for the parts where the tub meets the tile, and all else is fine, but I would like to seal these two edges as well.

Should I use a paintable caulking?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yep, use a paintable latex bathroom caulk. We always use PolySeamSeal (now owned by LockTite, available at Lowe's).

Comment: a.k.a. acrylic caulk?

Comment: Thanks to both. I don't have a Lowe's near me, but I should be able to find what I need.